# jquery adding elements to li not working

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, jquery-click-event

Hello everybody

I am having a problem with adding elements to `<li>` from jquery,

this is my jquery code

```
$(".div1").on('click','li',function(){
        var phonenumber = $(this).text();
        $("#phones ul").append("<li>"+phonenumber+"</li>");
    });
```

but when click on the `div1` nothing happend, what am i doing wrong please?

#### note

when i alter `phonenumber` i got the information that i need.

#### edit

```
    <div class="div1">
<li>press here to show your phone number</li>    
<div id="phones">
<ul>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you would need to click on the `li` inside `div1`, not `div1`

Comment: Could you post your html? I suspect you're mistaking class "." with id "#" on your jQuery selector.

Comment: For this to work, you need to click on the `li` element within `.div1`, and `this` within the function will refer to the `li` element. This may be the source of your confusion: it's hard to say without seeing the document structure.

Comment: @KevinB yes, that is exactly what i ment, sorry if i didnt mention that

Comment: @lonesomeday the same like Mr.Kevin, i did that

Comment: @VinnyFonseca how could i give you my html please?

Comment: Just post a html snippet in your question, like you did with the script.

Comment: Works awesomely [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KzbMt/) for me.

Comment: @Archer who could i open the question again to add my html please?

Comment: You can edit the question. The fiddle from Dream Eater works perfectly though. Upvoting that.

Comment: @VinnyFonseca yes it works, but why on my situation it is not

Comment: `li` elements can't be children of any element that isn't a `ul`. Please correct your html.

Comment: Works even with your case [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KzbMt/2/).

Comment: @tymeJV but i have a ul and the phones ul will find it, right?

Comment: @DreamEater my code is exactly as you did in the last link you give to me, why it works with you and doesn't work with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess what you are suffering from is not putting your code inside the `$(document).ready()` method.

Change your jQuery code to look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".div1").on('click', 'li', function () {
        var phonenumber = $(this).text();
        $("#phones ul").append("<li>" + phonenumber + "</li>");
    });
});
```

Comment: I already put the `document` as i told you, i can alter the phonenumber and i got the right information

Comment: yes yes :) i did some mistakes in the html :) i write </lable> instead of </label> , thank you it works

Comment: i didn't down vote my friend, really , i even can't upvote, i tried to up vote yoru ansewr, but i can't becaues i have just 11 reputation

Comment: @SimeoniPeraparota Oh, Can't help you there. Out of upvotes for the day.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML should be this:

```
<div class="div1">press here to show your phone number</div>
<ul id="phones">
</ul>
```

Then you can do:

```
$(".div1").on('click', function(){
    var phonenumber = $(this).text();
    $("#phones").append("<li>" + phonenumber + "</li>");
});
```